# Broadcast a program's audio to a media server

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, flash-media-server, pulseaudio

I'm trying to broadcast an application's audio output to a media server like Adobe FMS, Red5, or IceCast.

Is there a tool that can help me accomplish this, or a library that can help with building a custom solution in linux/windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg is an excellent option for this, transcoding and feeding into other streaming servers is where it shines, currently I'm using the following command to transcode an RTMP stream to 16x9 pixels in raw RGB24 format while also deleting the audio channel[s]:

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://192.168.99.148:8081/ -an -vf scale=16:9  -pix_fmt rgb24 -f rawvideo udp://127.0.0.1:4000
```

Of course the possibilities are limitless, if you can give more specific info about your case I might be able to help you construct the needed commands.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I'm trying to take the audio from skype-like program and publish it to a media server.

What I can't figure out it how to access the audio generated by that program using ffmpeg/jack or anything.

Comment: whats the program? does it expose its audio channels somehow? If not, maybe you can capture the master audio channel of the OS, never done that before but it should be possible.